# Pollard's $(p - 1)$ factorization method runtime

Tags: reference-request, factoring

Wondering if anyone knows a good reference for Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm's runtime? I was looking on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm) and the runtime cited there is $\mathcal{O}(B\cdot \log B\cdot \log^2 n)$. However, I can't find any reference on the Wikipedia page to this.

Where / how is this result proven?

Comment: This might help [Pollard’s p-1 and Lenstra’s factoring algorithms](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/courses/05-06/usra/charest.pdf)

Comment: Hi i read this when i was looking for some citation, i think she gives some runtimes for parts of the algorithm but not the whole process.

Comment: I think, because, the derivation is not straightforward. Usually, if there were a link, the Wikipedia guys provide it. It is interesting that there is none for this on the article.

Answer (score 2):

The $p-1$ method finds factors $p$ of an odd $n$ for which $p-1$ divides only (powers of) primes smaller than some user-selected bound $B$. It does this by computing
$$
\gcd(2^M - 1, n),
$$
where $M = \mathrm{lcm}([1, 2, \dots, B]) = 2^{\lfloor \log_2 B \rfloor}\cdot 3^{\lfloor \log_3 B \rfloor} \dots$. Note that the exponentiation $2^M - 1$ can (and should!) be performed modulo $n$. We can split the computation into three steps:

- Find the primes up to $B$. Using the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithmic_complexity), this takes time $O(B \log \log B)$. This only needs to be (pre)computed once, regardless of which $n$ we're factoring.
- Compute $2^M - 1 \bmod n$. Instead of computing $M$ explicitly, one may opt to exponentiate $2$ by $2^{\lfloor \log_2 B \rfloor}$, then by $3^{\lfloor \log_3 B \rfloor}$, etc. Each exponent has $O(\log_2 B)$ bits, and there are approximately $B / \log B$ primes, by the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). This gives us an exponent of $B / \log B \cdot \log_2 B = B / \log 2$ bits, which leads to $O(B)$ multiplications modulo $n$ using [binary exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Computational_complexity).
- A final GCD of integers at most $n$ sized, which [costs at most](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Complexity) $\log n$ multiplications of $n$-sized integers.

Unless $B$ is very small, the cost will be dominated by the second step, which has complexity $O(B \cdot \log n \cdot \log \log n)$ using [fast multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fourier_transform_methods), or $O(B \cdot (\log n)^2)$ using schoolbook multiplication. Wikipedia's bound appears to be the complexity of the variant which uses $M = B! = O(2^{B \log B})$ as the exponent, instead of $M = \mathrm{lcm}([1, 2, \dots, B])$.